# Gremlin - How to get in and out edges distinguishably for a list of vertices

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to get all the in and out edges with some specific labels from a given list of vertices.

The query that I am running currently is returning me a list of all the edges of all the vertices in a single list because of which I am not able to filter which edge belongs to which vertex.

How can I write this query so that I get all the in and out edges of the given vertices in data structure so that I can distinguish the edges of vertex from another?

```
g.V('2896897c-7346-47c0-b3be-ab808a7ca367', '89ed1880-1351-4de0-9c6f-b41c78a770d3').bothE('relation1','relation2').has('isActive',true)
```

With this query I am not able to differentiate the edges of vertex `2896897c-7346-47c0-b3be-ab808a7ca367` from vertex `89ed1880-1351-4de0-9c6f-b41c78a770d3`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the modern TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g=graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().as('v').bothE().group().by(select('v')).by(fold())
==>[
  v[1]:[e[9][1-created->3],e[7][1-knows->2],e[8][1-knows->4]],
  v[2]:[e[7][1-knows->2]],
  v[3]:[e[9][1-created->3],e[11][4-created->3],e[12][6-created->3]],
  v[4]:[e[10][4-created->5],e[11][4-created->3],e[8][1-knows->4]],
  v[5]:[e[10][4-created->5]],
  v[6]:[e[12][6-created->3]]]
gremlin>
```

Is this the pattern you were looking for?